# UiButton create in IB and use twice or more with change image

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uiimage

I have a button that I created in IB

In some time I output this button on screen

Then when I click on it, I hide it

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^
 {

     self.checkYESButton.alpha = 0.0f;


 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

     self.checkYESButton.hidden = YES;

 }];
```

}

then I want to take it again and change the image, but nothing happens

```
self.checkYESButton.hidden = NO;

[_checkYESButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkYESLeft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.checkYESButton.alpha = 1;
self.checkYESButton.frame =  CGRectMake( -100, 185, 106, 90);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f
                           delay:1
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                      animations:^
      {
          self.checkYESButton.center =  CGPointMake(176, 185);   
      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
      }
```

in the same way I bring another button that early not to use before, the button appears normal

**Update**

```
    self.checkYESButton.hidden = NO;

    [_checkYESButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkYESLeft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.checkYESButton.alpha = 1;
    self.checkYESButton.frame =  CGRectMake( -100, 185, 106, 90);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f
                               delay:1
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                          animations:^
          {
              self.checkYESButton.center =  CGPointMake(176, 185);

              // code is below decide this situation (only in this line)
              self.checkYESButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished)
          {
          }
```

Comment: why the underscore on _checkYESButton? and not self.checkYESButton?

Comment: maybe the difference is, but nothing happens, if I create a new button itself is all right, but it is not an option because I want to then create multiple buttons with the same functionality

Comment: hah when i use coordinates like self.checkYESButton.frame =  CGRectMake( 100, 185, 106, 90); I see button on screen <1 second and the button gone on down screen

Comment: I update post with decide method, but I can't understand how?